# knockoutjs 1.3 - observableArray not updating view

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I've got an issue with knockoutjs. I may be doing this completly wrong, but I have an observableArray being set with ajax data and it's working fine.
However when I run the ajax again, I remove all items (observableArray.removeAll) which works fine, but then the view just doubles up - I have all the previous items + all the new items.

My html/view looks like the following (I am using the containerless control flow in the 1.3 beta)

```
<div class="rowCollection">     
    <!-- ko foreach: products -->       
        <!-- ko foreach: Stock -->
            <!-- ko if: !DefaultSKU -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell product" data-bind="html: $parent.ProductName"></div>
                    <div class="cell level">                            
                        <input type="text" data-bind="valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', bind_stockLevel: $data.StockLevel" />          
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell infinite"><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: StockInfinite" tabindex="-1" /></div>
                </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->    
    <!-- /ko -->         
</div>
```

If I remove all of the child foreach statements it works fine - so seems to be a nesting problem?

Any ideas? Or is this a bug? Been trying to find anything relating to it, but not luck yet.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Example fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/danrichardson/nshaE/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently some type of bug related to either having consecutive containerless bindings or having containerless bindings as the root node in some cases.  I have not had a chance to fully research it yet, but did look into a simliar report on KO forums recently.

The workaround for the time being is to add another element in there like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/HPSbY/1/

I will make sure that I update this response, with any additional details or fix plans.

Comment: Ahhh man, so simple. Not ideal, but I tell you what it beats rewriting the whole thing which I thought I may have to do! Thanks a bunch man. Much appreciated.

Comment: Man, that was annoying. I had a container-less element calling a template. Changing that to a `<div>` fixed this issue for me, but it makes me sad. :(